# CakePHP: EXISTS or JOIN with UNION

Tags: sql, cakephp

I need execute next SQL query in CakePHP

```
SELECT * FROM products Product
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `products_likes` ProductsLike WHERE ProductsLike.product_id = Product.id AND ProductsLike.user_id = 9 )
OR 
EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `orders` Orders WHERE Orders .product_id = Product.id AND Orders .user_id = 9 )
```

or another way of implementation

```
SELECT Product.* FROM products Product
JOIN `products_likes` ProductsLike ON ProductsLike.product_id = Product.id
WHERE ProductsLike.user_id = 9

UNION

SELECT Product.* FROM products Product
JOIN `orders` Orders ON Orders .product_id = Product.id 
WHERE Orders.user_id = 9
```

How can I make this query in CakePHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create one function inside Product model and write below code:

```
$options = array(
        'conditions' => array(‘ProductsLike.user_id’=>9),
        'joins' => array(
            array(
                'alias' => 'ProductLike',  
                'table' => ‘products_likes’,
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'ProductLike.product_id = Product.id',
                ),
            ),
            array(
                'alias' => 'Order',  
                'table' => ‘orders',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Order.product_id = Product.id',
                ),
            )
        ),
        'fields' => array(“Product.*”),
        'group' => array('Product.id')
    );

 $returnData = $this->find('all',$options);
```

This will give you desired result!

Iinjoy...

Comment: Use group by product_id in the above query